Why $dimU = n-1$ in the proof of 9.12 in Linear Algebra Done Right 4th edition?
I have trouble understanding the proof of 9.12 (page 338) in Linear Algebra Done Right 4th edition. It is just a small part I need help with, but the context before it is a bit long.
Assumptions in the proof: $V$ is a nonzero finite-dimensional vector space over F, where F denotes either R or C, and $p \in V^{(2)}$.
The proof is proving that if $p$ is a symmetric bilinear form on $V$, then $M(p, (e_{1},...,e_{n}))$ is a diagonal matrix for some basis $e_{1},...,e_{n}$ of V
(Labeled (a) $\Rightarrow$ (d) in the book)
The proof uses induction on $n = dimV$. When $n=1$, the implication clearly holds. With $n>1$, if $p=0$, the implication also clearly holds.
So we deal with cases where $n>1$ and $p\neq0$, this means there exists $p(u,w) \neq 0$. Then since $2p(u,w) = p(u+w,u+w) - p(u,u) - p(w,w) \neq 0$, there exists $v$ such that $p(v,v) \neq 0$.
Let $U = \{u \in V:p(u,v) = 0\}$. The proof then states that, knowing $v \notin U$, $dim U = n-1$. How?  Why must its dimension be $n-1$, and not, say, $n-2$ or $0$?
It is trivially stated so it shouldn't be a big deal. But for some reason I can't see it.

$U$ is the kernel of $\varphi : u \mapsto p(u,v)$. Since $\varphi(v) \neq 0$, $\varphi$ is a non-zero linear form and hence, its kernel has dimension $n-1$ (just write rank-nullity equality for $\varphi$ if you don't see why).

@TheSilverDoe I am afraid I still don't understand. How can we be sure $U$ wouldn't be smaller? Like, how can we be sure there does not exist another $w\in V$ such that $p(w,v) \neq 0$?

The range of $\varphi$ is included in $F$, which has dimension $1$. So the range of $\varphi$ has dimension $0$ or $1$, but since $\varphi \neq 0$, it must have dimension $1$. By the nullity-rank theorem, the kernel has dimension $n-1$.

@TheSilverDoe Ahhh, I see now. I know the nullity-rank theorem by fundamental theorem of linear map so I didn't get you at first. Thank you.

By the way, this theorem is equivalent to the diagonalizability of symmetric matrices.

(Thanks @TheSilverDoe for the comments.)
We can see that $U$ = null$\varphi$, where $\varphi$ is the linear form $u \mapsto p(u,v) $.
Since $p(v,v) \neq 0$, dim range$\varphi > 0$, and since dim$F = 1$, we have dim range$\varphi = 1$. Then by the nullity-rank theorem (fundamental theorem of linear map), $$\text{dim } U = \text{dim null} \varphi = \text{dim }V - \text{dim range}\varphi = n - 1$$
